# What is the easiest way to repair damage to the corner of my vinyl siding of my home?

Tags: siding, vinyl-siding

My home was hit by a tree and my roofing company didn't feel comfortable fixing the damage in my siding. Is there an easy way to patch this? I have some quotes lined up with Siding Companies but they have both said they'll likely need to pull ALL of the siding off this side of the house to replace the corner part. Do you think this is accurate?

[image: Siding Damage]

Comment: Wow!  the siding companies must think people are exceptionally dumb.  It's a repair of the corner trim.  Replacement of the trim at most.

Answer (score 4):

There's a few ways to repair, No you don't have to take down any siding or your existing corner. Get a matching corner. you only need to use about 2 ft of your new 10 ft piece.it will fit directly over your damaged top portion and will look good.your new piece needs to be trimmed. Remove the nailing area completely. Now at the top of where your siding is damaged make 3 slits from top to bottom of damaged area one slit in center and one slit on either side so new piece won't bind but will be snug. Corner pieces are 10 ft long and cost about 15 dollars. Since your only using a few feet you have lots of practice pieces to play with to find your approach. Should take 5 minutes with a ladder, snips and a straight blade. You might have to hunt your piece down at a siding and roofing supply yard.

Answer (score 1):

I'd get some Bondo or other auto body filler. Get all the loose material out of there, rough up any smooth surfaces and apply the filler. Let it cure and then apply a second coat and try to match any texture to it with a sponge, roller or paint brush. Once you're satisfied, paint to match the trim.

I can't imagine why they'd have to pull off all the siding to repair, replace this. This is definitely a DIY project and would cost a fraction of what the siding companies would charge.